# Facebook API not returning correct attachment in messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I wrote the following JS code for getting attachment of a thread in using FQL

```
var a;
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT created_time, attachment,body FROM message WHERE thread_id = {chat_id} ORDER BY created_time ASC'
  },
  function(response) {
    a = response;
  }
);
```

But when I printed a known node of a, i found the no information of attachment is provided except an icon. And I manually verified that there should be an attachment. It is returning only those attachments which are link. No pdf or anyother attachments are not available.